# How to create an interrupt based on potentiometer value(s)?

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino to power a [motorized potentiometer](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/6/2/0/0/10734-01.jpg) and I wanted to know if there is a way to create an interrupt (stop the motor) when the potentiometer reaches within a certain range of values (like in one case stop motor if the potentiometer is between 1023 and 1000, another case between 500-600, and another between 0 and 100)?

I'm using the motor driver l293d, if that is helpful.

Comment: why do you need it to be an interrupt instead of polling?

Comment: I was about to edit my question until I saw your notification. It doesn't actually need to be an interrupt. All I want to do is stop the motor once the slider reaches a certain point on the motorized potentiometer. If you could explain anything that might help me out in this arena, feel free to answer.
Edit again: Not sure which one would be useful. I will be getting some data from an external source and if that data falls within some constraint I define, I want the motor to then stop as soon as this constraint occurs.

Comment: if you can, set the motor to run in the desired direction and just run an ADC measure + compare loop, which should eventually exit and turn off the motor once it gets into a region you consider "time to stop".

Comment: @PlasmaHH  is right, you may be trying to over complicate things. The polling method is fine if that is all your controller is worried about at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way that this would be handled to generate an interrupt would be to feed the voltage from the motorized pot into one side of a voltage comparator. The other side of the comparator would be fed from a settable voltage. The settable voltage level would be under software control either from the output of a D/A converter or through use of a digi-pot component. The latter is often the simplest to implement of you find an I2C controlled digi-pot.

As the motor controlled pot voltage changes it will eventually cross the threshold set by software to the other side of the comparator. This will make the output of the comparator change state. This output is used to generate the interrupt. Since the comparator threshold crossing could be either direction then it is necessary to use an interrupt input that can be configured to generate the interrupt on the positive or negative edge as needed depending on the current circumstances.

Comment: just adding that some microcontrollers have comparators available as peripherals, making this even easier.

Comment: like cypress semiconductor's PSoC chips with programmable logic and analog peripherals built into the IC and mapped to external IO pins

Comment: And some microcontrollers, in addition to having one or two voltage comparators built in with interrupt capabilities, also have a built in D/A converter! For those that do not have a D/A converter a timer can often be programmed to generate a PWM waveform that can then be filtered to produce the threshold voltage for one side of the comparator.

Comment: The ATmega328p of the most common "Arduino" *is* a microcontroller with a comparator.  It is unidirectional rather than window (I don't recall if there is a second) but it may with care be workable to combine this with knowledge of the direction in which the motor is being powered to decide on a setpoint.